# looking for a side panel which shows related content

Tags: wordpress, panel

I am one of the old guys, menu driven. My newly created website has a menu where I want to have accessible the most important pages/posts always.

If I open such a page (eg. from menu a) then I would like to have a side panel showing all/some of pages/posts which belong to the same categories/keywords.

does it exist? maybe some plugin? maybe out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by creating a page, putting a post block into it and adjusting the query to show only posts for the category I want.